# Is having no domain name bad?

Tags: debian

I have user and host names set, but the command `domainname` just returns `(none)`. Should I be concerned? Will this impact performance in any way?

Comment: Nope.  If you feel really bad you can use something like .local or .localdomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you (probably) don't need it.  Per TFM -

domainname - show or set the system's NIS/YP domain name

Are you using NIS/YP ?

You are probably thinking of a FQDN - hostname plus DNS domain.  Setting this in a file is an option (you'd have hostname.example.com or hostname.local or hostname.localdomain in /etc/hosts) it is better to put it in /etc/hosts.

```
user@darkstar ~ $ cat /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   darkstar darkstar.localdomain
```

Comment: Thanks - this lets me know how to add it. I probably don't need it since I'm not on a local network. I just don't understand what I did at installation since install asks for a domain name! Anyway, thank you.